# 110GB of hard drive eaten by scanner

Tags: hard-drive, pdf, scanner, scanning

I am in the process of scanning a couple of dozen reference books into pdf. The pre-optimized pfd's are around 150MB in size. For some reason since I've been doing it my c: drive has lost 110GB and is now full. I've run windirstat on it which only shows 170GB of my 280GB partition being used but yet windows explorer says its full.I've cleared temporary files but with minimal improvement.
Can anyone help please?
Thanks
Ben

Comment: As the program using links? (explorer seems to count those twice) or do you use shadow copies (so you can restore older versions) ?

Comment: @Hennes windirstat scans the entire harddrive and should include links and everything.

Comment: @8en How old is your harddrive?

Comment: Hi @Kris I've had the laptop about 2 years, running windows 7. Its an Asus N56VM

Comment: @8en then it really shouldn't be a disk issue yet, try click the start menu and type diskmgmt.msc and press enter. This should tell you information regarding how your disk setup is and see if there is anything fishy in there?

Comment: ran the disk management but everything looks normal. Its a HP scanner so maybe I'll post on their discussion group. Its defo to do with scanning, I ran a 200 pg book through the autofeed last night and it ate my last 11GB!

Comment: @8en: Did you run WinDirStat as admin?

Comment: Back up important data , then Run a Windows  chkdsk /r  on the hard drive, it is a free space issue which chkdsk should repair, you may have to run it up to 3 times sequentially to repair it completely. You could also have a hard drive in the early stages of death.

Comment: I've ran chkdsk /r and it didn't appear to have any effect. The only change is that now the hard drive is filling up on its own! I deleted some programs to free up 20GB, I've not done anything on the pc and the volume now has 3GB!. I've also ran WinDirStat as admin but not sure what difference that should make. I might run recovery.